# how do I fix my no so Search engine friendly urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I am working on my website. I have installed Joomla and got my website running. Problem is my urls are apwaring something like this http://www.example.com/example.com/index.php/information/aboutus instead of www.example.com/information/aboutus
My website is installed on a shared hosting server along with other websites so its in a folder named "\www.example.com" on the server. Also, My website is excuriating slow and I have been advised to enable enable gzip compression and Leverage browser caching.

Here's .htacees file's contents

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/example.com/
RewriteRule (.*)            /example.com/$1 [last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/example.com/
RewriteRule (.*)            /example.com/$1 [last]
```

Comment: Rues should work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! includes prepared .htaccess file.

1) it is located in root of the Joomla! installation - when installing, you should rename it from: **htaccess.txt** to: **.htaccess**

2) Now you need to enable  **Use URL Rewriting** parameter
(System - Global Configuration - Use URL Rewriting to YES)

index.php in URL will be removed.

**Use URL Rewriting**: "Use URL RewritingSelect to use a server's rewrite engine to catch URLs that meet specific conditions and rewrite them as directed. Available for IIS 7 and Apache. Apache users only!Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess before activating.IIS 7 users only!Rename web.config.txt to web.config and install IIS URL Rewrite Module before activating."

3) GZip compression you can enable in Global Configuration too (System - Global Configuration - Server - Gzip Page Compression)